# Resaltado texto MarkDown

Tags: markdown

Soy estudiante de **DAM**, y tengo unos apuntes que estoy redactando con **Bootsnote** en **Markdown**, pero no consigo resaltar texto, al igual que en un documento en papel con un marcador.

He buscado si seria posible realizarlo con una etiqueta `html` y `css`, por ejemplo así:

**Lorem Ipsum** es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas
y archivos de texto.

```
<span style="background:#FFFF00">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto.</span>
```

Pero no consigo que el documento se visualice con el resaltado.

Comment: El markdown no soporta el resaltado, y el código html, depende mucho del render de cada herramienta, si permite embeber código html junto con el md, y por cierto el de bootnote no pareciera tener esta funcionalidad.

Comment: Realice la prueba de tu codigo en este enlace (https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/) y funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamentablemente [`markdown`](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) no ofrece ninguna código para realizar el resaltado que esperas. La posibilidad de embeber junto al `markdown` código `html` existe en muchas herramientas. En el caso de `boostnote` esta funcionalidad no está habilitada por defecto. Para configurarla, hay que ir a la parte de preferencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y hay que permitir las etiquetas `html` "peligrosas". Luego podrás usar por ejemplo:

```
Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas
y archivos de texto.<span style="background:#FFFF00">Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto.</span>
```

o incluso

```
Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas
y archivos de texto.<mark>Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto.</mark>
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo probar un visualizador online de markdown para redactar el contenido:

aqui esta el link:

https://markdownlivepreview.com/

Para la sintaxis este en el link:

https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/

En cuanto a resaltado lo que puedes hacer en markdown es:

ITALICO; agrupando la palabra u oracion en * 
Ej: * soy italico *

BOLD: agrupando la palabra u oracion en ** 
Ej: ** esto es un bold markdown **

BOLD + ITALICO : es agrupando la palabra u oracion entre ***
Ej: ** esto va en negrita italico ***